# Find "string1" and delete between that and "string2"

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I'm using command line and sed. I need a command to delete from multiple files recursively.

I have left comments such as:

```
<!--String 1 -->
Code to delete goes here
<!--String 2 -->
```

So I need to delete string 1, the text in between and string 2, in all files in the current directory and below.

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "from multiple files recursively"?

Comment: @choroba: In current dir and subdirs. I commented your answer below, it should work with your sed line. Just update your answer with some recursive file search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use addresses:

```
sed -e '/<!--String 1 -->/,/<!--String 2 -->/d'
```

**Update:** to apply the `sed` command recursively to files under a path, you can use `find`:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec sed -e '/<!--String 1 -->/,/<!--String 2 -->/d' {} \;
```

Comment: What do you mean by addresses?

Comment: @Barney: [Addresses](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) are defined in `sed`'s manual page.

Comment: For all files and below: find . -type f -exec <sed line> '{}' \;

Comment: @Milde Could you formulate that into an answer if possible? :)