# sed: delete characters between two strings

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'd like to use sed to remove all characters between "foo=1&" and "bar=2&" for all occurrences in an xml file.

```
<url>http://example.com?addr=123&foo=1&s=alkjasldkffjskdk$bar=2&f=jkdng</url>
<url>http://example.com?addr=124&foo=1&k=d93ndkdisnskiisndjdjdj$bar=2&p=dnsks</url>
```

Here is my sed command:

```
sed -e '/foo=1&/,/bar=2&/d' sample.xml
```

When I run this, the file is unchanged.

The above is based on this example: [Find "string1" and delete between that and "string2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297932/find-string1-and-delete-between-that-and-string2)

Comment: Yes. When I add the -i flag, I end up with an empty file

Comment: This might need to be moved to the Linux / Unix stackexchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the *substitution* command instead of the *delete* command:

```
sed -e 's/\(foo=1&\).*\(bar=2&\)/\1\2/'
```

Comment: That seemed to work for me too, but can you please explain exactly what the command is doing?

Comment: `s/regex/replacement/` replaces the first match for `regex` in each line with `replacement`. `regex` can contain _groups_, and these _groups_ can be referenced with `\1`, `\2`, etc. This feature isn't strictly required in this case, and you could use `s/foo=1&.*bar=2&/foo=1&bar=2&/` instead.

Comment: And what happens if there are multiple `bar=2&` in the string? Because this code reads until the last one

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
 sed -i -e 's/\(foo=1&\).*\(bar=2&\)/\1\2/' your_html.xml
```

Comment: I tried this .. didn't work

Previous answer by `nosid` is working just fine

Comment: maybe the version of `sed` is different